# how to make ace editor work for collabrative work

Tags: java, servlets, ace-editor

I'm working on my academic project. It's called Cloud-IDE now I'm at initial stage where I'm making an web application which will accept code from user, compile it and output will be displayed to user in browser.
now suppose there are multiple people working on same code remotely, how can i provide something like one document(containing code) that will be displayed to all. anyone can contribute to it or at least view changes in real time.

I'm using ace-editor for code editor is there any way to provide collaborative work.

Server side: java servlet and stuff.

Comment: Look at [etherpad](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com).

[Scratchpad](http://scratchpad.io) uses this technique.